# delegate nil by replacing view

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have 2 way to access at the another pages on my app:

- *slide out* OR *tap on icon menu* to open my slide out navigation panel;
- Links are on the first page.

[image]

When I change page from menu or from the first page my delegate equals to nil, but when I run my apps on first time and I do a print on my delegate, delegate is ok.

I see "lol" message on console, but my menu won't open, and here my delegate equals to nil, and I think that's why I couldn't use my toggleLeftPanel function:

```
@IBAction func menuTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("lol")
    delegate?.toggleLeftPanel?()
}
```

So, I can't open my slide out navigation panel when I tap on the icon menu:
[image]

You can try my app here: https://github.com/Vkt0r/SlideOutSideBarTest

I don't see where is my problem between delegate and protocols, I'm looking on tutorial bu I can't found my mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delegate is nil can't use protocol functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548389/delegate-is-nil-cant-use-protocol-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncomment out the menuTapped method in NosOffresViewController

and replace nosOffresTapped with something like

```
@IBAction func nosOffresTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let window  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    let viewController = window!.rootViewController as! ContainerViewController
    let nosOffresViewController: NosOffresViewController = UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!
    nosOffresViewController.delegate = viewController

    self.delegate?.pushViewControllerInStack!(nosOffresViewController)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nosOffresViewController, animated: false)

}
```

In CenterViewContoller. Also need to declare ContainerViewContoller conforms to the NosOffresViewControllerDelegate protocol.

Okay, I figured out why it wasn't setting the delegate. UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()! returns a new instance every time it's call. So you'd set the delegate but then push a different instance.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it doesn't work, when I tap on iconMenu the slide out doesn't open

Comment: It's when i click on the picture to go at the another view, on the second time the iconMenu tap doesn't work

Comment: I understand. The code above works for me, but you have to do all of the steps. I downloaded your project, and I can navigate between screens by tapping cell or menu or a combination of both. You need to set the ContainerViewController as the delegate of your NosOffrasViewController.

Comment: Sorry for the late I'm looking at your post now

Comment: It looks working, I'm gonna see how you did it, thank you